# c# XML Schema validation

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have a nice XML file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Assets Path="C:\Users\r3plica\Google Drive">
        <Assetd>
            <FileName>Boomerang - Error codes.xlsx</FileName>
            <DisplayName>Boomerang - Error codes</DisplayName>
            <Description>This is the Boomerang error codes file</Description>
            <Tags>
                <Tag>Excel</Tag>
                <Tag>Boomerang</Tag>
            </Tags>
            <Categories>
                <Category>1</Category>
                <Category>4</Category>
            </Categories>
        </Assetd>
        <Asset>
            <FileName>Issue Tracker v5.xlsx</FileName>
            <Description>This is the issue tracker for Skipstone</Description>
            <Tags>
                <Tag>Excel</Tag>
                <Tag>Skipstone</Tag>
            </Tags>
            <Categories>
                <Category>1</Category>
                <Category>4</Category>
            </Categories>
        </Asset>
    </Assets>
```

and then I have my schema which I created like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema id="data"
        targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/data.xsd"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/data.xsd"
        xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/data.xsd"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >
      <xs:element name="Assets">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Asset" type="Asset" minOccurs="1" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:complexType name="Asset">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="FileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="Tags" type="Tags" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="Categories" type="Categories" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="Tags">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="Categories">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

As far as I can see looking at that, the xml file is invalid because the first element is Assetd and not Asset, but if I run my c# code:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("http://tempuri.org/data.xsd", "data.xsd");

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string msg = "";
doc.Validate(schemas, (o, err) =>
{
    msg = err.Message;
});
Console.WriteLine(msg == "" ? "Document is valid" : "Document invalid: " + msg);
```

it tells me the xml is valid...
If I use this code:

```
// Set the validation settings.
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add("http://tempuri.org/data.xsd", "data.xsd");
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

// Create the XmlReader object.
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(openFileDialog1.FileName, settings);

// Parse the file. 
while (reader.Read()) ;
```

I get this output in the console:

```
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Assets'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Path'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Assetd'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'FileName'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'DisplayName'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Description'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Tags'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Tag'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Tag'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Categories'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Category'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Category'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Asset'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'FileName'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Description'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Tags'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Tag'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Tag'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Categories'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Category'.
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'Category'.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please? It is killing me :(

cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: "As far as I can see looking at that, the xml file is invalid because the first element is Assetd and not Asset, but if I run my c# code:" I think you already know what is wrong.

Comment: I don't think you understand. I am trying to make it fail, yet it states it is valid.

Comment: The second part or node is valid. Think about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set default namespace in your xml, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"  ?>
    <Assets xmlns="http://tempuri.org/data.xsd">
        <Asset>
            <FileName>Boomerang - Error codes.xlsx</FileName>
            <DisplayName>Boomerang - Error codes</DisplayName>
            <Description>This is the Boomerang error codes file</Description>
            <Tags>
                <Tag>Excel</Tag>
                <Tag>Boomerang</Tag>
            </Tags>
            <Categories>
                <Category>1</Category>
                <Category>4</Category>
            </Categories>
        </Asset>
        <Asset>
            <FileName>Issue Tracker v5.xlsx</FileName>
            <Description>This is the issue tracker for Skipstone</Description>
            <Tags>
                <Tag>Excel</Tag>
                <Tag>Skipstone</Tag>
            </Tags>
            <Categories>
                <Category>1</Category>
                <Category>4</Category>
            </Categories>
        </Asset>
    </Assets>
```

Also, there is a number of other problems:

Path attribute is not defined in schema, 'Assetd' element is not defined.
maxOccurs="unbounded" need to be set in schema for xs:element name="Asset"

In case if you cannot modify xml, you need to remove target schema from xsd:

```
<xs:schema id="data"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/data.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

And register schema like this:

```
settings.Schemas.Add(null, "data.xsd");
```

Comment: thank you, I could not modify the XML but doing the second part of what you suggested worked perfectly :)