# Validating XML against XSD with <xs:any/> - Warning : Could not find schema information for the element

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to validate my XML files against an XSD to check if the files have the correct format.
In my XSd file I want the `Row` element to contain as many and whatever element possible, thus the `any` element.

With an online validator, I checked that the validity of XSD and checked my Schema on one of the files I want to check. Everything was valid.
The online validator is this one: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/

I based my parsing code on this topic : [c# XML Schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741469/c-sharp-xml-schema-validation)

I get that my files are not valid: `Could not find schema information for the element <MYELEMENT>`

The elements that are not found are the ones in my in the content of my Row element.

The complete .XSD is :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:any minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' processContents="lax" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
```

The XML I tested with is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <MODE_SAISIE_CT>'DEGRADE'</MODE_SAISIE_CT>
        <MODE_STATUT>'F'</MODE_STATUT>
        <MODE_LIBELLE>'Dégradé'</MODE_LIBELLE>
        <DATE_MODE_DEGRADE>'17/08/2011 15:28:17'</DATE_MODE_DEGRADE>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <MODE_SAISIE_CT>'STANDARD'</MODE_SAISIE_CT>
        <MODE_STATUT>'V'</MODE_STATUT>
        <MODE_LIBELLE>'Standard'</MODE_LIBELLE>
        <DATE_MODE_DEGRADE>'17/08/2011 15:53:06'</DATE_MODE_DEGRADE>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

How can I manage the parsing if I have an any element in my schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a complete XSD and input XML that exhibit the issue, it's unclear what to recommend, but perhaps this working example will help you identify your problem:

**This input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Row>
    <MYELEMENT/>
  </Row>
</root>
```

**Is valid against this XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Row">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The errors I thought I was getting are only warnings in fact so that doesn't mean that the file isn't valid. I checked the severity of the ValidationEventArgs.