# Why does this XML validate, when it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I have the following XSD files:

ReadFile.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="elsag:lprcore" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="elsag:lprcore" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="Read.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="reads" type="ReadFile" />
  <xs:complexType name="ReadFile">        
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="read" nillable="true" type="read">
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Read.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="elsag:lprcore" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="elsag:lprcore" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="Snapshot.xsd"/>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="GPS.xsd"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="guid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="read" type="read"/>
  <xs:complexType name="read">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="snapshot">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="timestamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="plate" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="state" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="confidence" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="overviews">
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="snapshot" type="snapshot"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="gps" type="gps" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="guid" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="camera" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Please note that there are more files that make up the XSD, but I don't believe they're relevant to the problem so I did not include them.

I'm using the following code to validate XML files being processed.  I want to reject any file that doesn't validate without errors:

```
StringBuilder validationErrors = new StringBuilder();
inDoc.Validate( schemas, ( o, e ) => {
    validationErrors.AppendLine( e.Message );
} );
if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( validationErrors.ToString() ) ) {
    . . .
}
```

I've passed the following XML file to the code above and the code does not generate any validation error messages for it.

```
<read>
  <timestamp>2015-07-17T16:20:18.1540000-04:00</timestamp>
  <plate>FED456</plate>
</read>
```

I would have thought that the lack of the `reads` tag surrounding the `read` tag would have caused the XML to fail validation.  Is the problem in the validation code or is it in the XSD or is this normal?

***EDIT:***

Here is the code that initializes the `schemas` variable:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add( "elsag:lprcore", @"XML\ReadFile.xsd" );
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "lack of the tag surrounding the tag would". The xml snippet you provided looks normal to me.

Comment: Looking at other related questions ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741469/c-sharp-xml-schema-validation?rq=1 ... you may need to add a namespace to trigger the validation? <read xmlns="ReadFile.xsd">....</read> ... it's been a while since I've had to do XML validation but I don't think it's enough to have added it via the XmlSchemaSet.

Comment: @AndresCastor: Sorry, I edited the question.  I had included less than & greater than around some tag names in the body & they were swallowed by the site's software.

Comment: @overslacked: Adding an XML namespace to the XML is irrelevant.  That XML, as it is, should not go through the validation code without some errors being generated, but it does.  What am I missing?

Comment: @overslacked: Turns out my comment about your comment was wrong, though it isn't clear to me why it was wrong.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to information posted in the answer by Glorfindel and the link posted by overslacked, I've been able to get the XML validation in my program to work.

The problem was that the program would not flag an XML file that does not contain a namespace as invalid. The cause is that the `XDocument.Validate` extension method creates an `XmlReader` object whose `XmlReaderSettings` property does not contain the `ReportValidationWarnings` flag.  As a result, the `ValidationEventHandler` delegate passed to the method is not called for these files.

To make the validation logic work, I defined a new extension method that includes the flag:

```
internal static class XmlValidationExtension {

    public static void ValidateWithWarnings( this XDocument doc, XmlSchemaSet schemas, ValidationEventHandler validationCallback ) {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas.Add( schemas );
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler( validationCallback );

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( doc.CreateReader(), settings );

        while ( reader.Read() ) ;
    }
}
```

This is essentially the same exact code from [the question linked to by overslacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741469/c-sharp-xml-schema-validation?rq=1), but where the `XmlReader` is created by calling the `XDocment` object's `CreateReader` method.

This code now considers any XML file which does not use the correct namespace to be invalid.  Any other part of the XML that does not match the XSD is also flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined

```
<xs:element name="read" type="read"/>
```

the `read` element is a valid root element for your XML. Every element which is an immediate child of `<xs:schema>` is eligible for being a root element (even those in an included schema).

Comment: OK, I'll buy that (I'm not very knowledgeable about how XSDs work).  How do I fix it so that the read tag is no longer a valid root element?

Comment: I think you can just remove this line. The `ReadFile.xsd` refers to the *type* `read`, not the *element* `read`.

Comment: Do you mean the line in the Read.xsd file?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: After making your change and some experimentation, I've found that the XML does not validate if I specify the namespace on the `read` tag, as in `< read xmlns:"elsag:lprcore">< /read>`.  This is what I'd expect.  But if I don't include the namespace, the XML does validate.  I don't understand why that is.  It works this way in VS, too.  Do I need to specify something to require the presence of the namespace in the XML?

Comment: After reviewing the thread referred to by overslacker in his comment to the question, I believe that what's happening is that absolutely no validation is being performed if no namespace is specified because it can't find a schema to use.  I may have to re-write the validation logic.